# Redux store overwritten instead of merged

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am writing an app in React Native using Redux. When I execute an action, instead of updating the store, it seems to replace the store, defining only the values that are explicitly stated in my reducer.

I am using `handleActions` from the `redux-actions` package. An example reducers looks like this;

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';

export default handleActions({
  DOCUMENT_GET_ALL_PENDING: state => ({
    isRefreshing: true,
  }),
  DOCUMENT_GET_ALL_FULFILLED: (state, action) => ({
    document: action.payload.documents,
    isRefreshing: false,
  }),
}, { isRefreshing: false, documents: [] });
```

For example, when it reacht `DOCUMENT_GET_ALL_PENDING`, the documents array gets set to undefined.
Here is what the creation of my store looks like;
I am using `redux-promise-middleware`, `redux-devtools-extension` and `thunk` middleware.

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  defaultState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware(), thunk)),
);
```

Any and all help or suggestions is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **merge** your states with the previous one. Right now you're just *returning the new state values*.

There are many ways to do it but you can use the `es6 spread operator`.

```
DOCUMENT_GET_ALL_PENDING: state => ({
    ...state,
    isRefreshing: true,
  }),



DOCUMENT_GET_ALL_FULFILLED: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    document: action.payload.documents,
    isRefreshing: false,
  })
```

Comment: Is there a way to override this default behaviour? I probably will have to look for another implementation to `combineReducers`?

Comment: You need to return a new merged state, since it is `immutable` and can't be mutated, there are some helper functions to do that as in [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) that might help